# What items in Skyrim's Bandolier mod grant the most carrying capacity?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

My current game of Skyrim has been augmented with the [Bandolier](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/16438/?) mod – a mod that allows you to craft leather pouches, bags, and belts that increase your carrying capacity. Items appear to be equipped by body region, but I am having trouble figuring out which items go where and what items are or not mutually exclusive.

So my question is somewhat twofold: which Bandolier items can be worn together at once, and of them which combination provides the biggest carry bonus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=66200826) has explained it quite nicely, you may take a look. It Says, There are 7 new slots for the equipment: Chest, Back Left, Back Right, Front Left, Front Right, Left Side and Right Side. Different items can be quipped into different slots, so you can combine up to 7 different pieces.

The items give you extra carry weight:

Small pouches - 25

Satchels, box pouches and bags - 50

Bandolier - 75

Large bandolier - 100

To see which slots the items are, using and how you can combine the items, there are screenshots given.